# import error and deleting an object from the ZODB

Tags: plone, zodb

I have a Zope server that hosts roughly a dozen Plone sites.  These sites started out on Plone 3, and they've been upgraded a few times.  They've been running Plone 4.3.1 for over a year.  Now I need to split these sites onto separate servers, so I exported each one to its own ZEXP file.

I'm getting an error on two of the sites, when I try to import them:

```
Error Type: ImportError
Error Value: No module named CacheSetup.content.caching_policy_manager
```

While these sites were on Plone 3, they used Products.CacheSetup.  All of the CacheFu related products were uninstalled on all of the sites before they were upgraded to Plone 4 and plone.app.caching was installed.  Apparently two of the sites still contain a single object that references Products.CacheSetup, so they can't be imported.

I exported one of the sites to an XML file and extracted the references to the CacheSetup content caching_policy_manager.  The XML is available here:

http://pastebin.com/9vgRNu0p

Based on the export I think the ID of the problem object is 1648800.  Can I use this information to delete this object from the ZODB, so the export will be importable again?

Comment: If you have uninstalled Products.CacheSetup, it shouldn't be mentioned in your xml-files anymore, probably didn't uninstall cleanly. The error might derive of them, not of an content-object. What happens, if you remove those xml-lines before exporting? Otherwise it cannot harm to run wildcard.fixpersistentutilities, as keul points out: As long as you don't go into its "expert-mode", you should be safe of possible damage.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this persistent stuff was hidden somewhere.

The [wildcard.fixpersistentutilities](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wildcard.fixpersistentutilities/) add-on can be commonly used cleaning those situations. Be careful and **read the documentation**.